# jQuery validation doesn't work without error

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

I don't undertand why my code doesn't work,there are no error messagges in console.
The propertyname in rule inside validation does refer to id or name of input form?
The library are correctly included in a general html template and an alert inside `$("#form").validate` works fine.

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
  $("#form").validate(alert("ciaoo"), //this alert works fine
  {
    rules:
    {
      nome: "required"
    },
    messages:
    {
      nome: " Inserisci il tuo nome!"
    }
  });
});
```

HTML:

```
<form id="form" action="Inserisci_Utente" method="post" >
    <fieldset>  

        <legend>Registrazione Utente</legend>
        <#if (messaggio??)>
        <#if (success??)>
        <div class="successo"><img src="img/success.png"/> <span>Operazione completata con successo.</span>
            <ul>

                <#list messaggio as mex>
                <li>${mex?html?lower_case?cap_first?trim} </a> </li>   
                </#list>

            </ul>
        </div>

        <#else>
        <div class="errore"><span></span>
            <ul>

                <#list messaggio as mex>
                <li>${mex?html?lower_case?cap_first?trim} </a> </li>   
                </#list>

            </ul>
        </div>
        </#if>
        </#if>
        <div class="fieldset">
            <fieldset> 
                <label>Nome</label>
                <input type="text" id ="nome" name="nome"/>
                <label>Cognome</label>
                <input type="text" name="cognome" />
            </fieldset> 
            <fieldset> 
                <label>Mail</label>
                <input type="text" name="mail" class="mail"/>
            </fieldset> 
        </div>
        <div class="fieldset">
            <fieldset> 
                <label>Username</label>
                <input type="text" name="username"/>
            </fieldset> 
            <fieldset> 
                <label>Password</label>
                <input type="password" name="pass1"/>
                <label>Ripeti la password</label>
                <input type="password" name="pass2"/>
            </fieldset> 
            <fieldset>
                <label>Ruolo</label>
                <input type="radio" name="ruolo" value="amministratore"/>Amministratore
                <input type="radio" name="ruolo" value="organizzatore"/>Organizzatore<br>
            </fieldset>
        </div>
        <fieldset>
            <input type="submit" name="registra" value="Registrami"/>
        </fieldset>
    </fieldset> 
</form>
```

Comment: Would have been best to show the _rendered_ HTML as seen by the browser rather than your raw un-rendered HTML file.

Answer (score 0):

As already stated by another answer, your `alert()` is breaking it.

You cannot just insert random JavaScript code into the `.validate()` method.  You are only allowed to place the specified options for the plugin, formatted as `{ key: value }` pairs, inside of the `.validate()` method.

```
$('#yourform').validate({  // this is the initialization of the plugin
    // only defined plugin options as key:value pairs allowed in here
});
```

By sticking an `alert()` inside of `.validate()`, you are effectively disabling the plugin from initializing.

**Otherwise, your code is working:  http://jsfiddle.net/P6uts/**

See documentation:  http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/

Comment: Ok now it works, The problem was that miss library additional_methods.js.

Comment: Now there is another problem: when click on submit,also if form is correctly compiled, they do nothing!Submit doesn't do nothing